# AJAX uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" with this AJAX call, I've tried a few workarounds but none seem to work... any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxManager2.php',
            data:{'name1=' $targetName, 'name2=' $sourceName},
            success: function() {
                alert("swap success");
            } 
        });
```

$targetName and $souceName are global variables so no problem there... I think I'm have trouble with the syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post/get method dont accept the `data` object as you try to post it.

You should change `data:{'name1=' $targetName, 'name2=' $sourceName},`

to

`data:{name1: $targetName, name2: $sourceName},`

Comment: Hi, I did this and yep it managed to fix the error, but I am now getting another error (jquery error) which I think must be beacuase of how I recieve the data on my php page; im running a filter input and sanitizing the string, but Im not sure if this is the correct way to recieve in this type of ajax...

Comment: you will have to update your question or make a new one

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the syntax of your object you provide to `data`. Keys should not contain `=` and the pairs should be separated by `:`. Try this:

```
data: { 
  name1: $targetName, 
  name2: $sourceName 
},
```